# Auto Responder email not being received from a PHP form

Tags: php, email, auto-responder

I have a website built using WYSIWYG WebBuilder.  Within that website is a PHP form registration page.  It was working perfectly until late last year.  When the user fills out the form, we get an email with the form data and the person registering would get a email confirming the registration. I still get the email but the other person does not. My hosting company is GoDaddy and they were really no help and the program I used to build the site helped the best they could. I'm sure it's some kind of setting somewhere, but I didn't want to start experimenting and really screw things up.

Any help would me most appreciated.

Greg

I tried to change a few settings within the program then I stopped getting the email, so I switched it back.

Comment: Are you sure you put all settings back?  We in Europe have the GDPR. Perhaps it is time to build a `double-opt-in`.